# Merge two data.tables to a new data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have two data tables

```
dt.1 <- data.table(id=c("id.1", "id.2", "id.3", "id.4", "id.5"), param = c("red", "green", "blue", "blue", "red"))
dt.2 <- data.table(red = c(0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.02), green=c(0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02), blue=c(0.01, 0.03, 0.03, 0.01))
```

which look like this

```
   id param
1: id.1   red
2: id.2 green
3: id.3  blue
4: id.4  blue
5: id.5   red

   red green blue
1: 0.02  0.01 0.01
2: 0.03  0.01 0.03
3: 0.04  0.01 0.03
4: 0.02  0.02 0.01
```

Now I would like to combine them and obtain a table like this

```
   id.1 id.2 id.3 id.4 id.5
1: 0.02 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.02
2: 0.03 0.01 0.03 0.03 0.03
3: 0.04 0.01 0.03 0.03 0.04
4: 0.02 0.02 0.01 0.01 0.02
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
library(data.table)
out <- merge(melt(dt.2, variable.name = "param"), # melt dt.2 before merging 
             dt.1,
             by = 'param',
             allow.cartesian = TRUE)
out <- dcast(out, rowid(id) ~ id, value.var = "value")[, id := NULL]
out
#   id.1 id.2 id.3 id.4 id.5
#1: 0.02 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.02
#2: 0.03 0.01 0.03 0.03 0.03
#3: 0.04 0.01 0.03 0.03 0.04
#4: 0.02 0.02 0.01 0.01 0.02
```

Comment: I obtain a warning which says: In melt.data.table(dt.2, variable.name = "param") :
  To be consistent with reshape2's melt, id.vars and measure.vars are internally guessed when both are 'NULL'. All non-numeric/integer/logical type columns are considered id.vars, which in this case are columns []. Consider providing at least one of 'id' or 'measure' vars in future.

Comment: @beni Yes, me too. But it's just a warning that you can ignore. From `?melt.data.table` : "If id.vars and measure.vars are both missing, all non-numeric/integer/logical columns are assigned as id variables and the rest as measure variables."

Answer (score 1):

tried with the below code :

```
dt.3<-dt.2%>%t()%>%data.frame()
cbind(dt.1,dt.3)%>%select(-param)%>%t()%>%as.data.frame()
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
     V1   V2   V3   V4   V5
id id.1 id.2 id.3 id.4 id.5
X1 0.02 0.01 0.01 0.02 0.01
X2 0.03 0.01 0.03 0.03 0.01
X3 0.04 0.01 0.03 0.04 0.01
X4 0.02 0.02 0.01 0.02 0.02
```

if u dont want as data frame or u want output as matrix use `as.matrix`

Comment: I am not familiar with pipes, but I will check it out. Thanks!

Comment: have u know sql ? similar to that subqueries in sql...pipes is used to perform multiple actions